# Trigger not updating at all

Tags: apex, trigger

This trigger which I wrote on Account is not updating contacts fields. I am not sure why. There are no errors. I tested updating records, fields but I see no updates on contacts.

```
trigger contactAccountTrigger on Account (after update) {
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    List<Contact> contactList1 = new List<Contact>();
    //System.debug('1st Loop- Outside');
    for(Account acc: Trigger.new){
        Account oldAccount = Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.ID);

        System.debug('1st Loop- inside');
         accountIds.add(acc.id);  


    }//End of Loop
    //System.debug('2nd Loop- Outside');
    If(accountIds.size()>0){
        Map<Id,Account> mapAccount = new Map<Id,Account> ([select id,Tier__c,Type, (select id,Account_Tier__c,Account_Type__c from contacts ) from account where id in :accountIds ]);
        List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
        for(account acc :Trigger.new)
        {
            //Account oldAccount = Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.ID);


            If(mapAccount.containsKey(acc.id))
            {
                Account accObj = mapAccount.get(acc.id);
                List<Contact> lstCont = accObj.contacts;
                for(contact c:lstCont)
                {
                    c.Account_Tier__c=acc.Tier__c;
                    c.Account_Type__c = acc.Type;
                    contactList.add(c);     
                }//end of for loop  
                System.debug('2nd Loop- Inside');
            }         

        } //end of Acc1 for loop 

        if(contactList.size()>0)
        {
           update contactList1;
        }

    }// End of accountIds.size()

}//End of trigger
```

Comment: Why don't you just use formulas for these fields on `Contact`?

Comment: Damn, that did work. I created a trigger for no reason.  I still wonder why it did not work?

Answer (score 1):

My primary recommendation here would be to simply convert these fields on `Contact` to be formulas.

Comment: I Agree Adrian. This is just for me to learn where I am making mistake for next time.

Answer (score 0):

You have two contact list variables 
1) List contactList1 - which you initialize at the start of the method, but never add to and try to update with.

2) List contactList - which you initialize after your soql query. You add values into but never update with it (because you update with contactList1)

Just use the one variable

Comment: It worked !!! that was the problem. Thank you Amul.

Comment: One quick question, would this trigger hit governor limits if I update more than 1000 accounts at once?

Answer (score 0):

So, since you are interested in learning, here is a much cleaner version of the trigger

```
trigger contactAccountTrigger on Account (after update) {
   Contact[] contacts = [Select Id,Account_Tier__c,Account_Type__c 
        FROM Contact 
        WHERE AccountId IN : Trigger.newMap.keySet()]; // accountIds
   for (Contact c: contacts) {
      c.Account_Tier__c = Trigger.newMap.get(c.AccountId).Tier__c;
      c.Account_Type__c = Trigger.newMap.get(c.AccountId).Type;
   }
   update contacts;  // even if list is empty, works fine w/o burning DML
}
```

> Note 1 - Formula fields are the way to go here as others have pointed
>   out
>
> Note 2 - You can extend the above to only care about Accounts where
>   the Tier or Type changed so as to avoid needless Contact updating of
>   benign Account changes
>
> Note 3 - This trigger logic could also be done in Process Builder as the same field values can be propagated to all children

Comment: Thank you cropredy. With Process builder, I would have hit the governor limits. Am I wrong? If I were to update so many records with this, this would have triggered the error with PB.

Comment: @calo - governor limits are always an issue in SFDC. If you had many Contacts per Account and a batch of Accounts changed tier/type, then potentially you could run into governor limits - depends on how much downstream processing is done on Contact DML.  But PB versus Trigger all else being equal shouldn't make much difference